# sqlite db not found on mobile device but works on emulator

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created an sqlite database consisting of a table and the database is populated with about 2000 rows.

I am able to query this table and everything is working fine when I do it via an emulator.

But when I test it on a mobile device, it is throwing following error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: person (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT name from person WHERE rowid = 292

When I tried it on a device, I was expecting my populated sqlite database to be automatically available on my device but based on above error, looks like that is not the case.

> I did have a look through past issues and they do not match my issue.
>
> 1. I did not set my own path for the db storage location.
>
>    > When I looked under Device File Explorer, the path for the database is 
>    >     /data/data/com.somepackage.myappname/databases/person
> 2. I have tried uninstalling the application and reinstalling it again which doesn't make a difference.

My sdk setup details if relevant.

> minSdkVersion 16
>
> targetSdkVersion 27
>
> Mobile device: Using Android version 8.0.0

Please advice how I can have the database automatically come with the app when installed (when I click run on Android Studio).

This is how I loaded the data into my database. This was ran only once and I have currently commented this code out.

```
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("person", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person");
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (name VARCHAR, name_size INT(8))");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("person.txt")));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO person (name, name_size) VALUES ('" + line + "', " + line.length() + ")";
            database.execSQL(sql);
        }database.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I initialise the database under onCreate method.

```
database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("person", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

When a button is clicked, the following method is executed. 
The error occurs on the first line in this method.

```
private String retrieveNextPerson(int randomIndex){
        //error on this raw query
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT name from person WHERE rowid = " + randomIndex, null);
        int wordIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(wordIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are not under the misconception that running the app on an emulator (or on any device) will alter the package so that the distribution will include the populated database

- to distribute a pre-populated database involves

  - a) populating the database (*generally using an SQLite management tool*),
  - b) copying this (*the file as that's the database*) into the assets folder and then :-
  - c) retrieving this from the assets folder.

    - using [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) makes this easy, *noting that with `SQLiteAssethelper` the DB file needs to exist in the databases folder (you'd very likely need to create this)*).

then I suspect that you are prematurely invoking :-

```
 database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("person", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Doing so would create the person database without the person table and thus result in the failure that you have described.

You need to load the data before using the above line.

Alternately if you added the following code immediately after `database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("person", MODE_PRIVATE, null);`

```
Cursor csr = database.query("sqlite_master",null,"name='person'",null,null,null,null);
if (csr.getCount() < 1) {
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (name VARCHAR, name_size INT(8))");
........ rest of the code that inserts data from the person.txt asset
}
```

The table would be created. However, it would be empty *( you could copy the data from the person.txt asset here )*

### Addition re comment :-

> Thanks for reply. Not sure if you missed the part where I mentioned
>   the database creation is already done and that part has been commented
>   out. I invoked the db creation once and loaded it with data and the db
>   is just sitting in the app now (at least for the emulator). The
>   initialisation you mentioned should open an existing db with an
>   existing table thus I don't see why that would be premature.

The following is a pretty solid rework of your code that will cater for what I believe could be the most likely underlying issues:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String DBNAME = "person";
    public static final String TBNAME = "person";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_NAME_SIZE = "name_size";
    public static final String ASSET_FILENAME = "person.txt";

    public static final String SQLITE_MASTER_TABLE = "sqlite_master";
    public static final String COL_SQLITE_MATSER_NAME = "name";

    static final int MIMINUM_ROWS_IN_PERSONTABLE = 1;

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    BufferedReader br;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkPersonTable(); // Notes sets db either way

        // FOR TESTING
        long rows_in_person_table = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,TBNAME);
        Log.d(
                "PERSON ROW COUNT",
                "The number of rows in the " +
                        TBNAME +
                        " table is " +
                        String.valueOf(rows_in_person_table)
        );
    }


    private void checkPersonTable() {

        db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        // Database will now exist but it may or may not contain the person table so check sqlite_master
        Cursor csr = db.query(
                SQLITE_MASTER_TABLE,
                new String[]{COL_SQLITE_MATSER_NAME},
                        COL_SQLITE_MATSER_NAME + "=?",
                        new String[]{TBNAME},
                        null,null,null
        );
        // Cursor will contain 1 row if the person table exists so check count
        int person_table_count = csr.getCount();
        csr.close();
        // Before attemtping to create the Person table ensure that the assets file exists
        // If not then throw a RunTime exception

        if (person_table_count < 1) {
            try {
                if (!Arrays.asList(getResources().getAssets().list("")).contains(ASSET_FILENAME)) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    throw new RuntimeException("Asset file " +
                            ASSET_FILENAME +
                            " not found in the assets folder." +
                            " The following assets were found" +
                            sb
                    );
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (person_table_count < 1) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBNAME +
                    "(" +
                    COL_NAME + " TEXT," +
                    COL_NAME_SIZE + " INTEGER" +
                    ")"
            );
            loadPersonsFromAssets();
        } else {
            // <<<<<<<<<< NOTE Optional will load data from assets if miminum nuber of rows
            //                 aren't in the person table
            if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,TBNAME) < MIMINUM_ROWS_IN_PERSONTABLE) {
                loadPersonsFromAssets();
            }
        }
    }

    // Load the person table from the Assets File
    private void loadPersonsFromAssets() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(ASSET_FILENAME)));
            String line, sql;
            int lines_read = 0;
            db.beginTransaction();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sql = "INSERT INTO " + TBNAME + " VALUES('" + line + "'," + String.valueOf(line.length()) + ")";
                db.execSQL(sql);
                lines_read++;
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Asset File " + ASSET_FILENAME + " not found in the assets folder.");
        }
    }
}
```

This will :-

- only attempt to open the database once setting the the SQliteDatabase object when it does so.
- will create the **person** database if it doesn't exist and then it will create the person table.
- Even if the database exists it continues to check that the table exists and will create it if it doesn't.
- An exception is if the asset file doesn't exist in the asset folder in which case a run-time exception will be raised (as if this is missing there is something drastically wrong as it should always exist as it's part of the package).
- It will also populate the table when created or populate the table if there are two few rows (depending upon the value of **MIMINUM_ROWS_IN_PERSONTABLE** ).

Should the asset file **person.txt** not exist then you would get an exception similar to :-

```
06-10 03:58:43.503 3097-3097/personthing.so50777840 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{personthing.so50777840/personthing.so50777840.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Asset file person.txt not found in the assets folder. The following assets were found
         found asset file :- images
         found asset file :- notperson.txt
         found asset file :- sounds
         found asset file :- webkit
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Asset file person.txt not found in the assets folder. The following assets were found
         found asset file :- images
         found asset file :- notperson.txt
         found asset file :- sounds
         found asset file :- webkit
        at personthing.so50777840.MainActivity.checkPersonTable(MainActivity.java:83)
        at personthing.so50777840.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            ... 11 more
```

- **Note** as can be seen, person.txt has been *"wrongly"* named **notperson.txt** to force the error.

Note at this stage the database will exist (due to the `openOrCreateDatabase`) and it will contain two tables (sqlite_master and android_metadata) but not the person table e.g :-

[image]

However, creating the correct asset file **person.txt** (renaming notperson.txt to person.text) will then result in the table being created and loaded with data:-

e.g. if person.txt is :-

[image]

Then running the App will result in the log containing :-

```
06-10 04:39:04.277 3325-3325/? D/PERSON ROW COUNT: The number of rows in the person table is 11
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Not sure if you missed the part where I mentioned the database creation is already done and that part has been commented out. I invoked the db creation once and loaded it with data and the db is just sitting in the app now (at least for the emulator). The initialisation you mentioned should open an existing db with an existing table thus I don't see why that would be premature.

Comment: No I didn't miss any part. However, the answer will be edited to included a pretty solid reworking that should overcome your issues.